# How to make field "Required" based upon "selected" value of Dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, validation, rule

I am trying to write a script which will impose validation rule **"required"** on a filed.

For example:

1. I am using 2 dropdowns ("need_accomodation" (YES/NO) and "accomadation_type(GUESTHOUSE/HOTEL)" )
2. When I select **YES** of **need_accomodation** the **accomadation_type** is displayed.
   I have used **hide()** and **show()** methods of jQuery.

But I need to apply the validation rule **required** on **accomadation_type**  appending with a **red (*)** on its label "Accomodation Type" .

Not getting a proper way to solve.

FYI: I am using jQuery.validation.js plugin.

Please suggest me how to solve  this problem.

Thanks in advance.

What I have achieved so far:

```
    {literal}
$("#need_accomodation").change(function() {
if ($("#need_accomodation").val() == "yes") {
     $("#accomodation_type").parent().show();
}
else {
    $("#accomodation_type").parent().hide();
    $("#accomodation_type").val('');
}
});
{/literal}

{literal}
$("#accomodation_type").parent().hide();
{/literal}{literal}
if ($("#need_accomodation").val() == "yes") {
     $("#accomodation_type").parent().show();
}
{/literal}
```

Comment: It would help a lot if you posted your jquery, to see what you've got so far...

Comment: Personal pet peeve - using a SELECT box to gather a boolean value (Yes/No) from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a conditional required clause based on a dependency expression. Also, as BradBrening in a comments suggested, you should use a checkbox to gather the value of need_accommodation from the user.

Here is the full explanation on how to use dependecy expressions in your validation rules:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression